# Как сохранить изменения в БД после редактирования Datagridview?

Tags: c#, база-данных, datagridview

Имеется DataGridView данные в него подтягиваются в коде ниже. Как мне реализовать сохранение изменений из DGV в БД по нажатию на кнопку ?

```
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(querystring, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(querystring, connection);
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        da.Fill(ds, "Events");
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        DataView view = new DataView(ds.Tables["Events"]);
        string str = "Сообщение LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
        view.RowFilter = str;


        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = view;
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался!Всё оказалось достаточно просто. Необходимо было в обработчик событий кнопки добавить код:

```
SqlCommandBuilder cmdbl = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
da.Update(ds, "Events");
```

Comment: Пожалуйста подскажите. А если имеется такой файл?

Comment: Файл БД или текстовый файл ?

Comment: Извините, отвлеклась в тот раз, не дописала. Уже сдано. Не помню какой файл...